# Proper way to shutdown an Ubuntu AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: shutdown, amazon-ec2

Sometimes I need to shutdown an Ubuntu AWS EC2 instance so my company does not get changed for the time if I'm not going to use it for a few days.  I'm not sure what is the proper or ideal way to do this.

To be clear, I don't have GUI access on this instance so the usual way of going to the GUI options at the top right and choosing Shut Down is not an option.

I do have access to the AWS Console page for this EC2 instance.

I'm using an Ubuntu 20.04 EC2 instance and I do have an EBS (Elastic Block Storage) volume mounted.

Here are some options I'm aware of:

1. From terminal, `sudo shutdown -h now`
2. From terminal, `sudo halt`
3. From the AWS Console page for the instance, choose `Instance state` -> `Stop instance`
4. other options ??

I'm not sure if one of these or something else is best, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You should do number 3 as explained on the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html#starting-stopping-instances). And also start it from the console as well.  From the link:

> **To stop and start an Amazon EBS-backed instance using the console**
>
> When you stop an instance, the data on any instance store volumes is
> erased. Before you stop an instance, verify that you've copied any
> data that you need from your instance store volumes to persistent
> storage, such as Amazon EBS or Amazon S3.
>
> In the navigation pane, choose Instances and select the instance.
>
> Choose Instance state, Stop instance. If this option is disabled,
> either the instance is already stopped or its root device is an
> instance store volume.
>
> When prompted for confirmation, choose Stop. It can take a few minutes
> for the instance to stop.
>
> (Optional) While your instance is stopped, you can modify certain
> instance attributes. For more information, see
> modify-stopped-instance.
>
> To start the stopped instance, select the instance, and choose
> Instance state, Start instance.
>
> It can take a few minutes for the instance to enter the running state

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 never worked to accomplish what you want. AWS recently snuck in a change to make 1 no longer work.

I would encourage option 3 - but widen your thinking. It is basically using the AWS API.  You can do that from the GUI AWS Console. You can do it the CLI `aws instance stop --instance-id`  . And you can do it through other programatic means such as an AWS SDK or more of a roll-your own approach and calling directly.

Now your VM may have certain permissions to work on the AWS API inherited from the instance profile, if there is one. What you can do is grant instance profile role the permission to stop instances (with maybe a condition or two to limit if necessary). Then you can do one of those handy commands from the shell on the instance - AWS CLI, for example.